# Bar button items not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6-beta6

I have implemented a Detail Disclosure Button on my table view cell to edit existing texts in the cells.  But the problem is that when I click on the Detail Disclosure Button it shows the existing text field but without any 'Edit' and 'Cancel' bar button items on the top.  I have given the segue identifier name as 'EditItem'.  I also have another segue which is named 'AddItem' that works properly and shows 'Edit' and 'Cancel' bar button item.  I have checked the code many times to find out the problem but didn't find any solution.  I want to know how to fix this problem.

I'm using Xcode 6 beta 6 SDK.

Comment: How are you adding the bar button items?  May we see your code?

Comment: Sure!Here is link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gylo67z2n00yc9i/TableView.zip?dl=0
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not adding the item the same way as you are editing the item.  Look at this:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddItem"]){
        UINavigationController *navigation = segue.destinationViewController;
        AddItemViewController *controller =(AddItemViewController *) navigation.topViewController;
        controller.delegate = self;
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditItem"]){
        UINavigationController *navigation = segue.destinationViewController;
        AddItemViewController *controller = (AddItemViewController *)navigation;
        controller.delegate = self;

        //
        NSIndexPath *indexpath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        controller.itemToEdit = _items[indexpath.row];

    }
```

Notice that for the `AddItem` segue you are getting the view controller like this:

```
AddItemViewController *controller =(AddItemViewController *) navigation.topViewController;
```

But for the `EditItem` segue you are getting it like this:

```
AddItemViewController *controller =(AddItemViewController *) navigation;
```

In your storyboard, the `AddItem` segue is connected to a navigation controller, which is then connected to your `AddViewController`, but the `EditItem` segue goes directly to the `AddViewController`.

Connecting `EditItem` to the same navigation controller `AddItem` is connected to should fix your problem.